# Blender Intro only renders one frame

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I just finished making my first intro in blender, and when I click animation it only renders the text for the first frame and the clouds for the first frame and then stops rendering, I have a few screenshots that could help solve the problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Hard to say, first time I see that render animation does't work. This look like bug. As first, try use newest Blender 2.77 instead old 2.76. If does't solve problem, try use "trial and error" method.Also I notice you have more than one scenes in .blend. Check  setup of both of them

Comment: Have you got anything happening in the "Post Processing"?  Untick those, see if that at least gets it going.

Comment: .. and the obvious one - you're pressing the "Animation button", not "Render".

Answer (score -1):

I actually fixed it by re-installing blender, my friend tried to render it and it worked for him so i decided to try re-installing blender.

Comment: This isn't really a solution, it would be better as a comment as no one can learn much from it.